# How to make every-time last option selected in case of service workers sites in simulators for devtools using given applescript?

Tags: macos, iphone, applescript, xcode-simulator

If you see the image, there are 2 sites: "linkedin.com and skype.com", I want if two sites are there, then everytime last option should be selected.

If only one site shows up, then only that should be selected.(this check should be included)

For now, my only need is last option should be selected if two options are showed up as shown in the image(linkedin.com and skype.com),then skype.com should be selected, else if one site shows up then only that should be selected.

Please help me to modify the below code itself, that will help me. It should be a small modification which I am not able to figure out in the below code.

```
tell application "Safari"
      activate
      delay 1
      set opened to ""
      tell application "System Events"
        repeat 5 times
            try
              set SimulatorOptions to (get every menu item of menu 1 of menu bar item "Develop" of menu bar 1 of process "Safari" whose name starts with "Simulator")
              log (count of SimulatorOptions)
              if (count of SimulatorOptions) > 0 then
                  set options to item 1 of SimulatorOptions
                  set pagename to name of menu item 2 of menu 1 of options
                  if (pagename as string is equal to "missing value")
                    log ("Still not opened")
                  else
                    click menu item 2 of menu 1 of options
                    set opened to "true"
                    exit repeat
                  end if
              end if
            delay 1
            end try
        end repeat
      end tell
      close (every tab of every window whose name is equal to "Favourites" or name is equal to "Untitled" or name is equal to "Start Page")
    end tell
    copy opened to stdout
```

[image: This is the image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate setting in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* assumes that **Safari** is already opened, **Simulator** is opened and **Safari** is opened in **Simulator**.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Safari"
        
        if not (exists ¬
            menu bar item "Develop" of ¬
            menu bar 1) then return
        
        tell ¬
            menu 1 of ¬
            menu bar item "Develop" of ¬
            menu bar 1
            
            set simulatorMenuName to ¬
                the name of ¬
                    (menu items ¬
                        whose name starts with "Simulator") ¬
                        as string
            
            if simulatorMenuName is equal to "" then return
            
            set simulatorMenuNameMenuItems to ¬
                the name of ¬
                    menu items of ¬
                    menu 1 of ¬
                    menu item simulatorMenuName
            
            if item 1 of simulatorMenuNameMenuItems ¬
                is not "Safari" then return
            
            repeat with i from 1 to count simulatorMenuNameMenuItems
                if item i of simulatorMenuNameMenuItems ¬
                    is equal to missing value then
                    set menuItemNumber to i - 1
                    exit repeat
                end if
            end repeat
            
            tell menu 1 of menu item simulatorMenuName to ¬
                click menu item menuItemNumber
            
        end tell
        
    end tell
end tell
```

---

**Notes:**

As coded, this will click the last **URL**, or first **URL** if only one is listed, on the **Safari** > **Develop** > **Simulator — …** menu under **Safari** on that menu.

The `tell application "System Events"` *block* in this *example* **AppleScript** *code* **stands alone** and **does not belong within** a `tell application "Safari"` *block* as shown in the *code* of the question.

If you prefer the *code* without the **AppleScript** *line continuation characters* and written in compact manner, then use:

```applescript
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Safari"
        if not (exists menu bar item "Develop" of menu bar 1) then return
        tell menu 1 of menu bar item "Develop" of menu bar 1
            set simulatorMenuName to the name of (menu items whose name starts with "Simulator") as string
            if simulatorMenuName is equal to "" then return
            set simulatorMenuNameMenuItems to the name of menu items of menu 1 of menu item simulatorMenuName
            if item 1 of simulatorMenuNameMenuItems is not "Safari" then return
            repeat with i from 1 to count simulatorMenuNameMenuItems
                if item i of simulatorMenuNameMenuItems is equal to missing value then
                    set menuItemNumber to i - 1
                    exit repeat
                end if
            end repeat
            tell menu 1 of menu item simulatorMenuName to click menu item menuItemNumber
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

---

**To address comment:**

> yes, but as i asked in the question itself, is it possible that you can modify my code only?, that i have posted.

If you want to use your *code*, but fixed to do what you want, then use:

```applescript
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    delay 1
end tell

set opened to ""
tell application "System Events"
    repeat 5 times
        try
            set SimulatorOptions to (get every menu item of menu 1 of menu bar item "Develop" of menu bar 1 of process "Safari" whose name starts with "Simulator")
            log (count of SimulatorOptions)
            if (count of SimulatorOptions) > 0 then
                set options to item 1 of SimulatorOptions
                set pagename to name of menu item 2 of menu 1 of options
                if (pagename as string is equal to "missing value") then
                    log ("Still not opened")
                else
                    repeat with i from 1 to count menu items of menu 1 of options
                        if name of menu item i of menu 1 of options is equal to missing value then
                            set menuItemNumber to i - 1
                            exit repeat
                        end if
                    end repeat
                    click menu item menuItemNumber of menu 1 of options
                    set opened to "true"
                    exit repeat
                end if
            end if
            delay 1
        end try
    end repeat
end tell

tell application "Safari"
    close (every tab of every window whose name is equal to "Favourites" or name is equal to "Untitled" or name is equal to "Start Page")
end tell

copy opened to stdout
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: @Ritesh Kumar,  RE: "yes, but as i asked in the question itself, is it possible that you can modify my code only?, that i have posted." --  Sorry but it was easier to write my own then to try and figure out the code in your question.  Also, the _code_  in your question is not well written in that the `tell application "System Events"` _block_ **does not** belong within the `tell application "Safari"` _block_, **and** the  `copy opened to stdout` makes no sense at all. -- As my code clicks the target menu item I see no reason you cannot incorporate it into whatever it is your are doing.

Comment: @Ritesh Kumar, RE: "yes, but as i asked in the question itself, is it possible that you can modify my code only?, that i have posted." --  See the _code_ in the **To address comment:** _section_ of the updated answer.

Comment: @Ritesh Kumar, RE: "just last request can you also modify the above code mentioned in the "To address comment", for the case of just 2 sites too?" --  Either of the different _code block_ already handles that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, just checking the new solution and will mark and upvote this answer. Extremely thankful to you. Also do let me know, how should I enhance my knowledge in applescripts if you know any sites to go through.

Comment: I have another query, should I create a separate question for this? Actually I was looking for a scenario, where instead of choosing the last option, we can select the current active site being used by the user. Let me know.

Comment: @Ritesh Kumar, RE: "I have another query, should I create a separate question for this?" --  Yes, as this question is answered and the site works better when there is one distinct question per question.

Comment: @Ritesh Kumar, RE: "we can select the current active site being used by the user." --  I do not think there is going to be an answer for this as **Simulator** doesn't appear to expose this to **AppleScript**.

Comment: @RiteshKumar We are not a script writing or code review service. If you have specific problems you need to solve with AppleScript (or other means), feel free to ask so you get answers with possible solutions. But don't expect people to debug your code or to solve all the problems you may have.